# Connect to MySQL database (over SSH) in python script

Tags: python, mysql, ssh

I am in a situation where I need to access a MySQL database running on another computer (Computer B). Unfortunately, the computers aren't on the same local network. The only way I found that I can access the SQL database on Computer B from my laptop (Computer A) is via SSH.

My question is, can I access the SQL database over SSH from python?

Comment: do you want to create the tunnel via OS or python. Fro OS you can try:  **ssh -N -L localhost:3306:localhost:3306  -p 22 root@dbserver.de** then you can connect via python over 127.0.0.1 port 3306

Comment: For clarity, you are saying that you can access port 22 on the server (Computer B), but not port 3306?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this snippet:

```
import pymysql
import paramiko
import pandas as pd
from paramiko import SSHClient
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from os.path import expanduser

home = expanduser('~')
mypkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(home + pkeyfilepath)
# if you want to use ssh password use - ssh_password='your ssh password', bellow

sql_hostname = 'sql_hostname'
sql_username = 'sql_username'
sql_password = 'sql_password'
sql_main_database = 'db_name'
sql_port = 3306
ssh_host = 'ssh_hostname'
ssh_user = 'ssh_username'
ssh_port = 22
sql_ip = '1.1.1.1.1'

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        (ssh_host, ssh_port),
        ssh_username=ssh_user,
        ssh_pkey=mypkey,
        remote_bind_address=(sql_hostname, sql_port)) as tunnel:
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user=sql_username,
            passwd=sql_password, db=sql_main_database,
            port=tunnel.local_bind_port)
    query = '''SELECT VERSION();'''
    data = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Ok thank you. I am using SQLExpress so there is no port (SQLExpress uses dynamic ports). Do you know how I modify pymysql.connect() to use SQLExpress?